# React - Redux State update but not rendered in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, codesandbox

I have a component `Details.js` where i am populating teams from 4 Leagues in a Select Dropdown

Depending on the team selected the states in `State.js` component are updated

The problem is that depending from the team selected, sometimes the state is rendered in `State.js` and sometimes no.

There are not errors in the console and in the redux tool the states are updated correctly.

I am using https://www.api-football.com/ to consume the data.

Here the relevant code

In the **reducers/index.js** i have created an initial state

```
RECEIVE_LEAGUE
  league:[],

case RECEIVE_LEAGUE:
  return {...state, leagueId: action.json};
```

In the **actions/index.js**

```
export const receivedLeague = json => ({
  type: RECEIVE_LEAGUE,
  json: json
});
```

I have added a dispatch in the `getTeamsDetailById(id)`

```
dispatch(receivedLeague(id));
```

In the `Details.js` component

I have added the state `leagueId` on top

and edited my `selectTeamStat` function

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');

  const selectTeamStat = (evt) => {
     const { value } = evt.target;
     setSelectedOption(value)
     getStats(leagueId, value);
  };
```

I have provided the demo in **codesandbox** reproducing the case [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bush-ob2ps) ( It is necessary to use Google Chrome extension CORS Unblock to see or any other extension unblocking the CORS )

To reproduce the case for example select Flamengo in Serie A and the state is updated and not rendered in the component but if you select Botafogo it is rendered. Why?

Comment: first of all what was the intention of keeping the stats in the redux state and the component state of the Stats-Component. In my optinion you can remove all local states of the Stats-Component and also all useEffect hooks.

Comment: Because the function getstast takes 2 parameters the leagueId and teamId

Comment: But the main issue is what you expect from your condition `if (
    teamsStatsWinHome &&
    teamsStatsWinAway &&
    teamsStatsDrawHome &&
    teamsStatsDrawAway &&
    teamsStatsLoseHome &&
    teamsStatsLoseAway
  )` this is false if any of those variables is null, undefined, false, '0' or 0 (see: [loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons) )

Comment: You are right, if you want to put the answer with the correct condition i accept the answer

Comment: Are you using redux thunk ? actually it is asynchrous by default so this maybe happened because of thunk . use redux saga instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (
  teamsStatsWinHome !== null && // maybe you also need to add `typeof object === 'undefined'`
  teamsStatsWinAway !== null &&
  teamsStatsDrawHome !== null &&
  teamsStatsDrawAway !== null &&
  teamsStatsLoseHome !== null &&
  teamsStatsLoseAway !== null
)
```

to avoid repetition you can also use but maybe the first way is easier to read

```js
const isNullOrUndefined = (object) => object === null || typeof object === 'undefined';

if(![
  teamsStatsWinHome,
  teamsStatsWinAway,
  teamsStatsDrawHome,
  teamsStatsDrawAway,
  teamsStatsLoseHome,
  teamsStatsLoseAway,
].some(isNullOrUndefined))
```

Comment: I have used typeof teamsStatsDrawAway == "number" for all and it works, i basically check if it is a number, i am not sure now whats is the best condition now

Comment: this should be fine as well.